# Determine actual height of a SpriteKit SKScene inside a SwiftUI View

Tags: layout, swiftui, sprite-kit

I have a SwiftUI View with a VStack of 3 SpriteKit SKScenes inside.
While scoreView and accelerometerView have a fixed height, gameScene does not.
It takes the remaining space and depends somehow on the device.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var gameScene = GameSKScene()
    @StateObject private var scoreView = ScoreSKScene()
    @StateObject private var accelerometerView = AccelerometerSKScene()

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
                SpriteView(scene: scoreView)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                            
                SpriteView(scene: gameScene)
          
                SpriteView(scene: accelerometerView)
                    .frame(height: 50)
    
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Now inside gameScene have problems setting up the scene because the scene itself has no information of its size.

I can get the width with `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` but how do I get the actual height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the `gameScene` `SpriteView` to fill the remaining space after accounting for the other two scenes. You can use `GeometryReader` ([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader)).

Example usage:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
       VStack {
          SpriteView(scene: scoreView)
              .frame(height: 50)
                            
          SpriteView(scene: gameScene)
              .frame(height: geo.size.height - 100)
          
          SpriteView(scene: accelerometerView)
              .frame(height: 50)
    
        }
    }
}
```